# A question regarding "Doe behaves as if he was / is the principal."

Tags: subjunctive-mood, mood

I got a few questions regarding this sentence: "Doe behaves as if he was / is the principal."  I know that if the speaker chose "was," it means the speaker knows Doe is not the principal. Now, consider only when the speaker uses "is":

Speaker's intent 1: (1) if the speaker does not know who the principal is and (2) he is just describing how Doe behaves, the speaker could say "Doe behaves as if he is the principal."

Speaker's intent 2: (1) if the speaker knows who the principal is, but (2) he does not choose to use "was"; instead, (3) he puts himself in Doe's shoes, who has not heard of the news yet and who is acting like a principal, the speaker could say "Doe behaves as if he is the principal."

Would you agree with what I have just said in the two paragraphs?

Comment: Without much more context determining a valid interpretation is pure guesswork. Assigning knowledge and or motivation to a speaker without being familiar with them in a way that the above text doesn't allow, yes - it *might mean* what you say, but it might mean any number of other things. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, could you [edit] to clarify. (Without making everything bold and enormous, please).

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I have edited and broken down a little bit.  The main question is to ask for all the possible interpretations when "is" is used by a speaker.